# unable to return arraylist from backing bean method

Tags: java, javascript, netbeans, xhtml

i want to intialize the array in javascript function(in xhtml) from the values of an arraylist in backing bean.I am able to access the arraylist elements individually

```
s2='#{sel_bean.retarr1(0)}';
alert(s2);
```

where retarr1() is a method in bean which returns the ith element of arraylist but when i am trying to do it inside for loop its returning the 0th element only.

```
for(i=0;i<s1;i++)
{
  alert(i);
  alert('#{sel_bean.retarr1(i)}');
  s2='#{sel_bean.retarr1(i)}';
  distarr.push(s2);
}
```

Comment: Javascript doesnt really know any ArrayLists, arent you confused with Java?

Comment: The term "backing bean" indicates that you are using JSF, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that you are using JSF from reading between the lines*

You could create the array push operations with jsf `ui:repeat`:

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{msel_bean.retarr1}" var="item">
  <h:outputText value="distarr.push(#{item})" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Another variant would be to initialize the array with `ui:repeat`:

```
var distarray = [
     <ui:repeat value="#{msel_bean.retarr1}" var="item">
       <h:outputText value="'#{item}', " />
     </ui:repeat>
];
```

Note that you will only get an array of strings.